# Conan package manager - how to remove folders during conan install?

Tags: c++, conan

I have a local `conanfile.py` to consume a package, the package is already located on the local cache (`~/.conan/`).

In the `conanfile.py` there is the `imports()` function in which I copy some files from the package into my build folder.
I have two files with the same name in different directories and I copy them to the same directory and rename one of them.

After I do that, I am left with an empty directory I want to remove, but can't find a way to do so from `conanfile.py`, every attempt seems to remove the folder before the files gets run. My imports looks as follows:

```
class SomeConanPkg(ConanFile):
    name = "SomeName"
    description = "SomeDesc"
    requires = (
        "SomePkg/1.0.0.0@SomeRepo/stable")        

    def imports(self):
        # copy of 1st file
        self.copy("somefile.dll", src=os.path.join("src"), dst=os.path.join(build_dest))
        # copy of 2nd file to nested directory
        self.copy("somefile.dll", src=os.path.join("src", "folder"), dst=os.path.join(build_dst, "folder"))
        # move and rename the file to parent directory
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(build_dst, "folder", "somefile.dll"), os.path.join(build_dst, "renamed_file.dll"))
        # now build_dst/folder is an empty directory
```

I have tried to use `conan tools.rmmdir()` or just calling `shutil.rmmtree()` but all of them seems to run before the files gets copied.
I also tried to add a `package()` or `deploy()` member functions and execute the remove inside but these methods don't seem to run at all (verified with a debug print).

Any ideas?

Comment: The ``copy()`` actually happens before the ``shutil.copy2`` and other potential removes that you can do. It seems that the issue is that Conan does other operations on the copied files, so it doesn't expect that those files will be moved or renamed (like how a dll rename will not break the consumer, that at build time expects the original dll name?). Doesn't seem doable within the recipe.

Comment: Damn, too bad. Do you know if there is a way to copy a file & rename it along the way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended us solving it in the package creation side.
Renamed the files as I wanted and then just consumed them

Comment: That sounds a better approach indeed, than trying to juggle in the consumer side. If the package is that difficult to consumer, that is probably an indicator that the package should be fixed, I wrongly assumed that you had no control over the package that you were consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Try `conan remove <package name>` . If you do not know the exact package name you can also use `conan search` to see the list of packages before you use `conan remove`.